# Is there a hotkey for switching on/off a layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers

I would like to know if there is a hotkey in qgis for switching on/off a layer. I have a task where I have to open and close a layer quite frequently. Doing it by a mouse is too time-consuming and annoying when you have got to do it over and over again. If there is no hotkey for that is there a way to define a hotkey(some python script maybe?).

Comment: Spacebar works as long as the layer is selected

Answer (score 4):

There are three useful actions to do that. But they are not for switching on/off a layer individually.

Navigate "Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts...", and search "selected layers". You'll see three actions like in the image. Set adjacent keys (for simplicity) as shortcuts for them.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In QGIS there is not a specific hotkey by default for your task. 
By default, you have Crtl+Shift+U that shows all the layers and Crtl+Shift+H that hide them. 
Anyway, you can define a hotkey to hide or show the selected layer. 
Just go, in the menu Setting, to select Keyboard shortcuts and create the hotkey for the options Show selected layers and Hide selected layers.

Answer (score 1):

And if your need is linked **with a given layer** you're able to write a python script **targeting this layer** and assign a shortcut to the script ...